# OLTP to OLAP with CQRS or SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, nservicebus, olap, cqrs

## *Background Information*

Our application reads/writes from 3 components:

1. ASP.NET MVC 3 customer front end website (write actions)
2. Winform verification tool at stores (write actions)
3. Silverlight Dashboard for tenant (95% aggregate reads 5% write actions)

(3) is the only piece that can use some performance improvements.

Our storage is Sql Server Standard OLTP database that has stored procedures that aggregate data consumed by the silverlight app.

When using database tuning advisor or execution plan we don't see any critical indexes missing and we rebuild indexes with sql agent job.

Most of the widgets are sparklines

- x = time selected by interval (day, week, month, year)
- y = aggregate (sum,avg,ect)

currently we return about 14 - 20 points per widget. Our dashboard opens with 10 widgets initially.

Our dimensions would be: tenant, store, (day,week,month,year)

Our facts: completed, incomplete, redeemed, score ...

I know a denormalized table will remove needing sql server from recalculating for
store managers, franchise owners, corporate viewing the data ~50 (simultaneous users)
each time

I'll be honest if we go with OLAP it will be my first hands on experience with it.

## *Questions*

What is the long term solution for a rich reporting dashboard?

I would assume OLAP.  If so, how would you keep it up to date to be near realtime dashboard that we have today?
Putting a maintenance page while OLAP rebuilds itself is not an option.
Ideally, we would want to do this incrementally and see Nservicebus (which we use today already) as a great bridge to update these 
denormalized views.   Do we put these denormalized views in oltp as just another table or is there a way to incrementally update OLAP datasource?

## *References*

http://www.udidahan.com/2009/12/09/clarified-cqrs/

http://www.udidahan.com/2011/10/02/why-you-should-be-using-cqrs-almost-everywhere%E2%80%A6/

Comment: Not knowing your reporting table requirements or your plans for migrating to SQL Server 2012, but they'll be offering an amazing read-only option index option called the [columnstore index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492088(v=sql.110).aspx) It offers fantastic performance characteristics for aggregations. You state you need real-time. *Every one* needs real time, until they have to start to pay for it. Once clients see the cost (hardware, development, execution time, etc) of having real-time, I often find "oh, up to the hour is good enough"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
“Putting a maintenance page while OLAP rebuilds itself is not an option.“
```

Why would you say that? The OLAP cube is available while it’s rebuilding.
There are several ways you can configure how the refresh works, ROLAP, HOLAP and MOLAP. You can have automatically refreshes at X hours or even make the data available in real-time. Try reading about proactive caching on SSAS, it may give you some ideas.

Comment: from seeing how team foundation server rebuild option, however, this is a true rebuild not just updating metrics.  This was a misconception on my part.  Thanks for clearing it up.